# Css flexbox content overflows

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following header with items and am using flexbox

```
        <header class="header">
        <div class="row container header__items">

            <h2 class="header__logo">Test</h2>

            <input type="text" class="input input--outlined" placeholder="Serach">

            <h5>Karim</h5>
            <h5>Karim</h5>
            <h5>Karim</h5>
        </div>
    </header>
```

And my scss code with flexbox classes i have

```
.header{
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

  &__items{
    display: inherit;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: red;
  }

 &__logo{
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: inherit;
 }
}
```

The following has the header__items overflowing on the y-axis. How can i stop this. See the attached screenshot on the red background. Also it doesn't center the red box even if i reduce its height.Am using materialize css. I have also created https://codepen.io/geowan/pen/gOpzOEm which shows this.

[image]

Comment: Where do you want the serach box to be?

Comment: @skm I want the searchbox to be in the middle and to span the remaining width of logo and other right side items

Answer (score 0):

Yash - there are so many things wrong with your markup. Firstly, Materializecss have already created a navbar for you - why re-invent the wheel? They don't use flexbox, but you can adapt their example to create what you need.

https://materializecss.com/navbar.html

Secondly, you are using a row inside a div that is also a container - and there are no cols inside. Here's how it works:

**.container**

This restricts the width of content. Consider it the inner-wrapper.

**.row**

Rows sit inside containers - they add margin-bottom for spacing, and are a container for cols.

**.col**

cols sit inside rows and lay your content out in columns. Please refer to the grid system, you are not suing elements as per the documentation.

https://materializecss.com/grid.html

```
input {
  width: auto !important;
}

.links {
  display: flex; 
}
```

In terms of fixing your code, I removed .row from the element, put justify-content:space-between on the header__items to force the three items away from each other, wrapped your right hand links in a new div (and display: flex on these) and then changed the input width to auto, because the materialize default is 100% (so it was spreading the available width of your div.

https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/MWwGwme

You need to spend some time in the docs and use the provided examples until you know what you're doing.